# Store queryset in local storage

Tags: caching, django-forms, local-storage, pickle

I want to store a queryset result from a form submission to restore its state once it is accesed again. I have tried using,localStorage,cache but both of them are giving problems that instead of saving the data as a queryset, the valus are stored as a string.

views.py

````
def Elective_HD_list(request):
  
    try:
        Elective_list= localStorage.getItem("list_HD")

        form=ElectiveForm_HD()
    except AttributeError:
        Elective_list=[]
        form=ElectiveForm_HD()
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=ElectiveForm_HD(request.POST or None)
        
        if form.is_valid():
               
                Elective_list=form.cleaned_data['Elective_ID']
                request.session['form_data'] = Elective_list
                localStorage.setItem("list_HD",Elective_list) #stored as a string instead of query

               
               
               
    return render(request,"homepage/Elective_HD_list.html",{"form":form,"elective_list":Elective_list})```



Is there a way to store queryset which I can access in further iterations as needed
````